# Regular Expression.how to add optional character at end of regex

Tags: regex

I just want to write a regular expression 4 digits and '.' and 5 digits and optional 'A'

Ex: `1111.2345A` where `A` is optional.

```
^[0-9]{4}[\.][0-9]{4}$
```

This reg ex will give `1111.2345`, but how to add Optional 'N' at last.

Comment: Use `[A-Z]{0,1}` for an optional letter

Comment: Why `{0,1}`? Use `?`: `^[0-9]{4}\.[0-9]{4}A?$`

Answer (score 9):

Use `?` at the end for characters:

`[A-Za-z]?`

This will match at most 1 presence of a character (lower or upper case).

Answer (score 6):

You can check for a character zero or one times with this:

```
'[A]{0,1}'
```

Put that at the end of your string and it will try and match the character 'A' zero or one times. You may also use the symbol `?` to match zero or one times. All about preference.

Answer (score 2):

To get a single, optional `A` at the end, append `A?` to your regular expression:

```
^[0-9]{4}[\.][0-9]{4}A?$
```

Btw. instead of `[0-9]` you could use `\d` which stands for 'digit':

```
^\d{4}\.\d{4}A?$
```